# Camel, Bindy and composed fields

Tags: apache-camel, unmarshalling

I'm trying to unmarshal a csv that have composed fields. For instance, in the following example

> "order1","foo@email.com","(test1;45),(test2;89)"

The third attribute would represent a list of two items (but the size of the list is variablet), each item having a name and a price. The @Link annotation only works in one-to-one annotation, so it is not an option. The @OneToMany annotation in csv only works for writting so is neither an option.

The csv is written by non technical stuff, so a complex format is not an option either.

Is it possible to manage this requirement?

The java class to instantiate would be, in this case, something like this:

```
public class Order {
  private String name;
  private String email;
  private List<Item> items;
}

public class Item {
  private String name;
  private int price;
}
```

Many thanks in advance